# Как применять алгоритмы STL в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, stl

Как применять алгоритмы STL в Qt, на примере `QStringList` и `set_difference`, например? Если это возможно, конечно.

Comment: [How to use STL in Qt](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/40255-How-to-use-STL-in-Qt).

Comment: и в чём проблема? у всех кьютовских контейнеров есть `begin()` и `end()`, их и надо передать в `std::set_difference()`...  учти, что последняя оперирует только на предварительно отсортированных наборах...

Comment: @fat-zer спасибо! Разобрался.

Comment: @Fat-Zer как ответ?

Comment: @Suvitruf, к выходным, наверно, напишу, если не забуду... буду не в обиде, если кто-то меня опередит... хотя первая реакция, если честно, у меня была закрыть, как «решено/опечатка»...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У всех кьютовских контейнеров есть методы `begin()` и `end()` (а также `cbegin()` итп), которые возвращают STL-совместимые итераторы; есть они в том числе и у [`QList`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#begin), наследником которого является `QStringList`.  Их и надо передать в STL'евские функции обобщённых алгоритмов.

```
QSet<QString> strongWords{"криворучкие", "дураки", /*...*/};

//....
QString userOpinion = getUserOpinion();
QStringList userOpinionWords = qSort(userOpinion.split(QRegExp("\\s+")'));

QStrinList inapropriateWords;

std::set_difference(userOpinionWords.cbegin(), userOpinionWords.cend()
                    strongWords.cbegin(), strongWords.cend(),
                    std::inserter(inapropriateWords, inapropriateWords.begin()));

if (!inapropriateWords.isEmpty()) {
    QMessageBox::info (QString ("Ваш отзыв очень важен для нас, но следующие слова неприемлимы: ").append(inapropriateWords.join(", ")));
    throw std::runtime_error ("Пользователь был груб, поэтому мы бросим исключение и не будем его ловить.");
}
```

Также надо помнить, что по своей сути [`std::set_difference()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) принимает на вход только упорядоченные контейнеры...